# Cruisecontrol.Net git not seeing modifications

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

I've just set up a Cruisecontrol.Net server under Apache+Mono and pointed the sourcecontrol to my GitHub project. I made a commit and pushed it but CC is not detecting the changes even though it reports them in the output:

```
[MyProject:INFO] [Git] Calling git log origin/test --date-order --name-status -c "--after=Fri, 29 Jun 2012 12:19:25 GMT" "--before=Fri, 29 Jun 2012 13:12:24 GMT" --pretty=format:"Commit:%H%nTime:%ci%nAuthor:%an%nE-Mail:%ae%nMessage:%s%n%n%b%nChanges:"
[MyProject:DEBUG] Starting process [git] in working directory [/home/ccnet/MyProject/build] with arguments [log origin/test --date-order --name-status -c "--after=Fri, 29 Jun 2012 12:19:25 GMT" "--before=Fri, 29 Jun 2012 13:12:24 GMT" --pretty=format:"Commit:%H%nTime:%ci%nAuthor:%an%nE-Mail:%ae%nMessage:%s%n%n%b%nChanges:"]
[MyProject:DEBUG] Not setting PriorityClass on [/home/ccnet/MyProject/build/git] to default Normal
[511:DEBUG] [MyProject git] process exited event received
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] Commit:3d386b1277003c83c63e7e13bde2803bfe952d40
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] Time:2012-06-29 14:00:34 +0100
[510:DEBUG] [MyProject git] standard-error stream closed -- null received in event
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] Author:Robin Elvin
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] E-Mail:rob@-------.com
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] Message:Merge branch 'master' into test
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git]
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git]
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] Changes:
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git]
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] Commit:fc134027f059a1dada0295bbd2d04cbea6eeb57b
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] Time:2012-06-29 14:00:24 +0100
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] Author:Robin Elvin
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] E-Mail:rob@-------.com
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] Message:Set complete status on sync and fix tests (issue #2 #3)
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git]
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git]
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] Changes:
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] M       File1
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] M       File2
[509:DEBUG] [MyProject git] M       File3
[507:DEBUG] [MyProject git] standard-output stream closed -- null received in event
[MyProject:INFO] No modifications detected.
```

Here is the relevant block from my config:

```
<sourcecontrol type="git">
<repository>git@github.com:xxxx/MyProject.git</repository>
<branch>test</branch>
<workingDirectory>/home/ccnet/MyProject/build</workingDirectory>
<autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
</sourcecontrol>
<triggers>
<intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="30" buildCondition="IfModificationExists"/>
</triggers>
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there was a bug in the git source control provider that prevented ccnet from detecting git merge commits.

Just upgrade to the latest ccnet version (1.8.x) should fix your problem.

Comment: I've marked this as the accepted answer although I cannot test as I've moved over to Jenkins now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I made another commit and pushed and this triggered a build.

No idea why it wasn't before. Will keep checking in case it's a bug.